# jQuery read data object and wait $.each is done

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my data object

```
{
    "teachers":{
        "0":{
            "info":{
                "id":"1",
                "age":"22",
                "driverlicense":"yes"
            }
        },
        "1":{
            "info":{
                "id":"2",
                "age":"51",
                "driverlicense":"yes"
            }
        },
        "2":{
            "info":{
                "id":"1",
                "age":"25",
                "driverlicense":"no"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I try to read is the `info` object, and take the information from there.

My code

```
$.each(data.teachers, function(item) {
    if(item.info.age < '25'){
        // stores in array
        yTeachers[item.info.id] = item.info.age;
    }
});
```

But it gives me `undefined` back.

Is it possible to read the array `teachers` if the `$.each` is done? Sometimes it is still running when I run another function. Maybe use something like `promise`?

Comment: teachers is not an array, is an object with key "0", "1", etc. You will have to use for(key in data.teachers)

Comment: @KevinB, sorry.. I've edited the post.

Comment: @user1655756 fortunately $.each does support objects, so the op could continue to use $.each in this case if used properly.

Comment: `$.each(obj, function( **index**, item) {...` <- the first argument is just the key in this case

Comment: @adeneo thanks, it works!

Answer (score 1):

Use this for reference check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/4fygqw63/#&togetherjs=0GMBbclcc0):

```
var data = {
    "teachers": {
        "0": {
            "info": {
                "id": "1",
                "age": "22",
                "driverlicense": "yes"
            }
        },
        "1": {
            "info": {
                "id": "2",
                "age": "51",
                "driverlicense": "yes"
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "info": {
                "id": "1",
                "age": "25",
                "driverlicense": "no"
            }
        }
    }
};



  var  yTeachers=[];
    $.each(data.teachers, function (i, item) {
        if (item.info.age < 25) {
            yTeachers[item.info.id] = item.info.age;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you to store `ages > 25` on `yTeachers` as an object.

```
var json = {
    "teachers": {
        "0": {
            "info": {
                "id": "1",
                "age": "22",
                "driverlicense": "yes"
            }
        },
        "1": {
            "info": {
                "id": "2",
                "age": "51",
                "driverlicense": "yes"
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "info": {
                "id": "1",
                "age": "25",
                "driverlicense": "no"
            }
        }
    }
};

var yTeachers = [];
$.each(json.teachers, function(index,item) {
    var id = item.info.id;
    var age = item.info.age;

    if(age < 25){
        // push it in array
        yTeachers.push({id:age});
    }
});

console.log(yTeachers);
```

Comment: How can I check if the `$.each` is done? So I can invoke another function? I want to sort the array based on the age, but I can do that only if all the ages are in the array.

Comment: @AlterEgo, $.each() iterates over the array/object synchronously, so you can simply run your code after the $.each(); e.g `$.each(obj,function(i,item){}); yourfunction();`

Answer (score 1):

> wait $.each is done

No need to wait for `$.each` to be done just call your variable after.

`$.each`'s callback has 2 arguments, 1st for item `index/key` and 2nd    for item `value`.

1. with arrays to check last item called and done use `index == array.length -1`

   ```
    $.each(array, function(index, value){
    if(index == array.length -1){
      console("$.each is done and last item called");
     }
    });
   ```
2. with objects to check last key called and done use `key == Object.keys(obj).pop()` and this is your case.

   ```
    $.each(obj, function(key, value){
    if(key == Object.keys(obj).pop()){
      console("$.each is done and last item called");
     }
    });
   ```

```js
var data = {
  "teachers": {
    "0": {
      "info": {
        "id": "1",
        "age": "22",
        "driverlicense": "yes"
      }
    },
    "1": {
      "info": {
        "id": "2",
        "age": "51",
        "driverlicense": "yes"
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "info": {
        "id": "1",
        "age": "25",
        "driverlicense": "no"
      }
    }
  }
}
$.each(data.teachers, function(i, item) {
  if (item.info.age < 25) {
    alert(item.info.age);
  }
  if (i == Object.keys(data.teachers).pop()) {
    console.log("Done")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```